# Drop Down menu not working on Touch Window PC/PC Tablet

Tags: angularjs, windows, touch, tablet

```
<select name="fullname" ng-model="user.fullname" ng-blur="focusedfullname=false" ng-focus="focusedfullname=true" required >
<option value="">-- Names--</option>
<option value="1">VIKAS KOHLI </option>
<option value="2">ABC </option>
<option value="3">XYZ</option>
</select>
```

When I touch the dropdown box, the dropdown appears, but when I try to select any dropdown list view, my app crashes.

Why does this happen?

Comment: getting any errors before crashing??

Comment: remove `ng-blur="focusedlanguage=false"` and check

Comment: @SaEChowdary unable to see any errors. Whenever I clicked app crashes

Comment: @RameshRajendran I check but it doesn't work